# Magento : Fixed Amount Discount on Whole Cart Promo Not Working

Tags: magento-1, shopping-cart-price-rules, tax, totals

I've created a promo rule for customers who spend $150, I will give $50 discount. Please find attached screenshots for conditions and actions settings.[image: Conditions section]

[image: Actions section]

When cart total is above $150, promo rule isn't getting applied. Promo rule applies, only when subtotal is $150 + ($150 * 10%).

Can anyone help me fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: you have set rule on subtotal not in grand total.

Comment: Hi @DhirenVasoya, Thanks for the reply. I've checked conditions section and actions section, but I couldn't find option for Grand Total. May I know how can I set the rule for Grand Total.